# How can i do random background color on Android studio with kotlin

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, random, background-color

I want to change background color randomly actually i just wanna red or green background randomly how can i do this with kotlin language on android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Random` class to generate a random true/false value, and then use that to choose between red or green.

```
view.backgroundColor = if Random().nextBoolean() Color.GREEN else Color.RED
```

Comment: I didn't know nextBoolean method it's so useful for me.Thank you